# Is it possible to use 々 and co (ヽ、ゝ、...) even if the shortened part is from another word?

Tags: symbols

For exemple is it possible to write 部分々数 in place of 部分分数 or is it considered bad practice?

I am asking this primarily because it is convenient for taking notes. But I would want to know if it is possible to use in every document or if it should be reserved for personal use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, it's not to be used across words as you mentioned.

> - [会社社長]{かい・しゃ・しゃ・ちょう}　→　The president of a company
> - [民主主義]{みん・しゅ・しゅ・ぎ}　→　Democracy
> - [市神神社]{いち・がみ・じん・じゃ}　→　Ichigami Shrine

From [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B8%8A%E3%82%8A%E5%AD%97):

> 「会社-社長」「民主-主義」のように意味が区切れる場合は使用しないことが原則だが、「公演会々場」のように使われることもある。特に、結婚や葬式に関しては、同じ漢字を直接繰り返すことは、再婚や不幸の繰り返しを連想させ縁起が悪いため、「結婚式々場」、「告別式々場」と表記することが多い。

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll accept this one because it mentions exceptions to the rule that macraf's answer does not address but macraf's answer is good too and I regret that only one answer can be accepted.

Answer (score 4):

It is definitely a bad style.

---

Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration_mark#Kanji) first states:

> Using 々 instead of repeating kanji is usually the preferred form, with two restrictions:  (...) the repetition must be within a single word.

Then admits in longer compound words it is sometimes used:

> the abbreviated 民主々義 is only occasionally seen

Nevertheless you can see dōnojiten used with disregard for all rules:

[image: KenkunJinja-shamusho]